# Make choice of Optimized (armv6 armv7) architecture appear in XCode project settings

Tags: iphone, xcode

In XCode, when I open project settings, I only see the following two choices for the setting "Architectures": 'Standard (armv6 armv7)' and 'Optimized (armv7)'.

How can I get the choice of 'Optimized (armv6 armv7)' to appear?

I'm using XCode 3.2.3.

Comment: What do you expect "Optimized" to do?

Comment: I was not sure of the difference between 'Standard' and 'Optimized', and I thought that Optimized would yield better performance.  I need to support 3G phones so I need to have armv6 selected.  I noticed people mentioning 'Optimized (armv6 armv7)' on forums, which lines up with hotpaw2's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the iOS SDK for 4.0.x, Apple renamed the old "Optimized (armv6 armv7)" to "Standard (armv6 armv7)", so you've already got it to appear, just under a different name.

Answer (score 6):

It's misleading. Choose armv6&7 if you're developing for iPhone 3G or earlier. 3GS and later, including iPad, use arm7, so if those are the devices you're targeting, you can get code more optimized for those newer devices by choosing armv7, no backward compatibility. (For targeting all devices, old and new, choose armv6&7.)